# Does java -jar option alter classpath options

Tags: java, classpath

I have a jar file which mentions the main class in the manifest.
When I try to execute the jar using the following command

```
java -cp .;./* com.foo.MainClass
```

The code executes and works.

When I try to execute the jar using the following command

```
java -cp .;./* -jar myjar.jar
```

I get class not found execptions for some jars which are in the same folder as myjar.jar. I hoping that the -cp option will include those jars in class path.
I modified my code to print java.class.path property. In the first case it listed all jars in the current directory, in second case it just listed myjar.jar

I also modified the manifest to add Class-Path element to it with all jars. Then the second command works. But in my code I am trying to load a aribtrary class whose name is provided at command prompt, so I want the class path to contain all jars in a folder. How do I make the second command work in this scenario?

Comment: Have a look at [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/). That should solve your CP issues.

Comment: @flash: Probably not. He says he does not know the extra class path at compile-time (otherwise he could just add it to the manifest).

Comment: Sounds like you have to use your own classloader (that adds things back in according to your environment).

Comment: @Thilo, true, I need to use load additional classes at runtime. From the response below, looks like I need to do some class loading of my own using URLClassLoader.

Comment: Another option would be to resort to a batch file or some other kind of wrapper (so that you can use wildcards or programmatic discovery).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jar/),

> An executable JAR must reference all the other dependent JARs it
>   requires through the Class-Path header of the manifest file. The
>   environment variable CLASSPATH and any class path specified on the
>   command line is ignored by the JVM if the -jar option is used.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that if I want to load a aribtrary class whose jar file is present in the same place as my jar file (and not mentioned in my manifest), I need to use URLClassLoader to load that jar explicitly?

Comment: Well, you could add something like `plugins/*` to your manifest classpath. The folder for the jar files would be fixed, but all jars in there should be picked up.

Comment: Or maybe not: "However, class path wildcards are not honored in the Class-Path jar-manifest header." :-(

Answer (score 0):

You will need your own classloader to deal with this.  `-jar` only respects the information in the Manifest and wildcards are not allowed there.

You might find the example of a reloadable class useful: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReloadClass.html

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://anshuiitk.blogspot.com/2010/10/class-path-settings-in-excecutable-jar.html) is a good discussion on this issue.