# NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/binding

Tags: java, groovy, jar, classpath

I'm trying to evaluate Groovy script inside a Java app by using GroovyShell.

Problem: My program compiles ok, but gives me a NoClassDefFoundError at run-time.

TestClass.java:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

class TestClass {
    static Binding binding;
    static GroovyShell shell;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world.");
        binding = new Binding();
        shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
        Object value = shell.evaluate("5 ** 5");
    }
}
```

Then I compile with:

> > javac -cp %GROOVY_HOME%\embeddable\groovy-all-2.1.1.jar TestClass.Java
>
> > jar cfm TestClass.jar Manifest.txt TestClass.class

It compiles without error. Then I run it:

> > java -jar TestClass.jar

```
Hello, world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/Binding
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Binding
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

Full error text: http://puu.sh/2gOrx

I've also tried running it with the same -cp as I compiled it, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you try "java -cp TestClass.jar;%GROOVY_HOME%\embeddable\groovy-2.1.1.jar TestClass"?

Comment: Same error. http://puu.sh/2hlYG

Comment: Does %GROOVY_HOME%\embeddable\groovy-2.1.1.jar exist? At my side, it is groovy-all-2.1.1.jar.

Comment: Oh, I'm actually using groovy-all-2.1.1.jar as I should be. I typed it wrong in my posts though. http://puu.sh/2hn9E

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global classpath, for example, CLASSPATH environment and "-cp" option, won't take affect if you are running an executable JAR. Please refer to this post for details: [Does java -jar option alter classpath options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396132/2086065).

[java - the Java application launcher document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Instead, you need to set Class-Path in manifest file. Check the following sample.

File structure

```
|-- Manifest.txt
|-- TestClass.class
|-- TestClass.jar
|-- TestClass.java
`-- lib
    `-- groovy-all-2.1.1.jar
```

Manifest.txt (don't forget to add a new line ending for last line)

```
Main-Class: TestClass
Class-Path: lib/groovy-all-2.1.1.jar
```

And execute the same commands in your question to generate and run an executable JAR. For more information, check this wiki page: [Setting the path in a Manifest file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_in_a_Manifest_file).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the JAR directly, load the JAR into the `classpath` and specify the class to run:

```sh
$ java -classpath $groovyJar:TestClass.jar TestClass
```

It's a little hacky because the `Main-Class` is specified in the manifest but then taken from the command line.  On the plus side, you don't have to hard-code the `Class-Path` into the manifest.

The path to the [Groovy JAR](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) has changed since this question was asked a very long time ago.  Assuming `groovy` is in your **PATH**, one way to locate the Groovy JAR is:

```sh
$ groovyHome=$(dirname $(dirname $(which groovy)))
$ groovyJar=$groovyHome/lib/$(basename $groovyHome).jar
```

And the result will be something like:

```sh
$ which groovy
/Users/dem/apps/groovy/groovy-2.5.2/bin/groovy
$ echo $groovyJar
/Users/dem/apps/groovy/groovy-2.5.2/lib/groovy-2.5.2.jar
```

To build a JAR you can test with locally, create the Groovy file:

**com/example/HelloWorld.groovy**

```
package com.example

class HelloWorld {

   static void main(String[] args) {
      println "Hello, world."
   }

}
```

Then issue the commands:

```sh
$ groovyc com/example/*.groovy
$ jar cfv HelloWorld.jar com/example/*.class
added manifest
adding: com/example/HelloWorld.class(in = 2829) (out= 1220)(deflated 56%)
$ ls -o
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 dem  1708 Oct  5 01:15 HelloWorld.jar
drwxr-xr-x  3 dem    96 Oct  5 01:10 com
$ java -classpath $groovyJar:HelloWorld.jar com.example.HelloWorld
Hello, world.
```

*Note:* The Groovy JAR (`groovy-2.5.2.jar`) is 5.4MB, and the latest version (`groovy-3.0.0-alpha-3.jar`) is 7.5MB.