# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with log4j

Tags: java, linux, jar, classloader

I am trying my first project with gradle. My project has a dependency with log4j-1.2.17.jar  After my project is built, a jar file is generated. I try to run this with the following:

```
java -classpath ".:/home/ec2-user/dlsvr/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" -jar dlsvr.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at com.secutrans.dlsvr.DLSvrMain.<clinit>(DLSvrMain.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

But if I build a fatjar with gradle, the fatjar works without specifying any classpath. The dependency statement in gradle is like:

```
dependencies 
{
    compile files("/home/ec2-user/dlsvr/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AbtPst is correct. It is a classpath problem.

Here is similar question.
[Does java -jar option alter classpath options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396100/does-java-jar-option-alter-classpath-options)

An executable JAR must reference all the other dependent JARs it requires through the Class-Path header of the manifest file. The environment variable CLASSPATH and any class path specified on the command line is ignored by the JVM if the -jar option is used.

My problem was resolved by adding classpath in manifest file of the jar through gradle.

```
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to include the log4j.jar in your class path

Refer to:
[Does java -jar option alter classpath options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396100/does-java-jar-option-alter-classpath-options)

```
An executable JAR must reference all the other dependent JARs it requires through the Class-Path header of the manifest file. The environment variable CLASSPATH and any class path specified on the command line is ignored by the JVM if the -jar option is used.
```

Comment: I have specified inside the command through classpath:           java -classpath ".:/home/ec2-user/dlsvr/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar" -jar dlsvr.jar

Comment: is that allowed? i think -jar option and -classpath option cannot be used with each other. i think they are mutually exclusive